# Reg : Compare 2 datefields in salesforce

Tags: apex, datetime

I have a EndDate field in my visualforce page. when user enter any date.it's taking the previous date.Suppose if my user enter day after tomorrow date it will take tomorrow date i have to validate that user must enter the date is not more than 24hours from current date and time how i can check

```
Endtime = DateTime.newInstance(enddate, Time.newInstance(timeHH, timeMM, 0, 0));

   DateTime d = System.now();

  if(Endtime>=d)
  {
   System.debug('*******Endtime:' +Endtime);
   Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Notenterlessthanvalue'));
  }
```

my code is working here i have to check if the user enter time is less than 24hours in past then i have to save the record.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Date.daysBetween(secondDate)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm):

> - `daysBetween(secondDate)`
>     Returns the number of days between the Date that called the method and the specified date.